# Cannot read module of undefined - error with cloudinary module

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, cloudinary, shim

I am using mean stack application. The below is my public/js/main.js

```
(function(requirejs) {
    'use strict';

    // -- DEV RequireJS config --
    requirejs.config({
        // Packages = top-level folders; loads a contained file named 'main.js'
        noGlobal: true,
        packages: ['main'],
        shim: {
            'jquery': {
                exports: '$'
            },
            'lodash': {
                exports: '_'
            },
            'angular': {
                exports: 'angular',
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'angular-cookies': {
                deps: ['angular']
            },
            'angular-sanitize': {
                deps: ['angular']
            },
            'angular-animate': {
                deps: ['angular']
            },
            'angular-resource': {
                deps: ['angular']
            },
            'text': ['require'],
            'app': ['angular'],
            'ui-router': ['angular'],
            'angular-xeditable': ['angular'],
            'restangular': ['lodash', 'angular'],
            'angular-bootstrap': ['angular'],
            'semantic': ['jquery'],
            'pickadate': ['jquery'],
            'datetimepicker': ['jquery'],
            'pickadatedate': ['pickadate'],
            'angular-breadcrumb': ['angular'], 
            'angular-file-upload-shim' : {
                deps: ['angular']     
                },      
            'angular-cloudinary' :{
              deps: ['angular','angular-animate','ui-router','angular-resource']  
            } ,            
            'angular-file-upload' :{
                deps : ['angular']
            }            

        },
        paths: {
            'text': '../lib/requirejs-text/text',
            'angular': '../lib/angular/angular',
            'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery',
            'lodash': '../lib/lodash/dist/lodash.min',
            'semantic': '../lib/semantic/build/packaged/javascript/semantic',
            'angular-sanitize': '../lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize',
            'angular-animate': '../lib/angular-animate/angular-animate',
            'angular-cookies': '../lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies',
            'ui-router': '../lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router',
            'angular-resource': '../lib/angular-resource/angular-resource',
            'angular-bootstrap': '../lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap',
            'restangular': '../lib/restangular/dist/restangular.min',
            'pickadate': '../lib/pickadate/lib/picker',
            'datetimepicker': '../lib/smalot-bootstrap-datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min',
            'textangular': '../lib/textAngular',
            'pickadatedate': '../lib/pickadate/lib/picker.date',
            'angular-xeditable': '../lib/angular-xeditable/dist/js/xeditable.min',
            'moment': '../lib/momentjs/moment',
            'd3' : '../lib/d3/d3',
            'angular-flash' : '../lib/angular-flash/angular-flash',
            'angular-breadcrumb': '../lib/angular-breadcrumb/dist/angular-breadcrumb.min',                        
            'angular-cloudinary' : '../lib/cloudinary_ng/js/angular.cloudinary',
            'angular-file-upload' : '../lib/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min',
            'angular-file-upload-shim' : '../lib/ng-file-upload-shim/angular-file-upload-shim.min'
            //'jquery.cloudinary' : '../lib/cloudinary_js/js/jquery.cloudinary',
            //'jquery.iframe-transport': '../lib//blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport',
            //'jquery.fileupload' : '../lib/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload',
           //'jquery.ui.widget' : '../lib/blueimp-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget'

            //   'text' : '/lib/'
            // You can also define a module here, e.g. a local module that doesn't support RequireJS
            // or map a longer path to a shorter name
        }
    });

    // Load the app...
    require(['angular', 'text', 'semantic', 'angular-cookies', 'ui-router',
            'angular-resource', 'angular-sanitize', 'angular-animate','angular-bootstrap', 'common/main',
            'restangular', 'angular-breadcrumb','angular-file-upload-shim','angular-cloudinary','angular-file-upload'
        ],
        function(cookies) {
            var startModuleName = $('script[data-main][data-start]').attr('data-start');
            if (startModuleName) {
                var origModuleName = startModuleName;
                startModuleName = startModuleName.replace('.', '/');
                require([startModuleName + '/main'], function() {
                    $(function() {
                        console.log('Bootstraping auth: ' + origModuleName);
                        angular.bootstrap(document, ['common', origModuleName]);
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    );
})(requirejs);
```

**angular.cloudinary.js**

```
(function (factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // Register as an anonymous AMD module:
        define([            
            'angular'
        ], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals:
        factory(angular);
    }
}(function (angular) {

  var angularModule = angular.module('cloudinary', []);

  var cloudinaryAttr = function(attr){
    if (attr.match(/cl[A-Z]/)) attr = attr.substring(2);
    return attr.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g,'$1_$2').toLowerCase();
  };


  ['Src', 'Srcset', 'Href'].forEach(function(attrName) {
    var normalized = 'cl' + attrName;
    attrName = attrName.toLowerCase();
    angularModule.directive(normalized, function($sniffer) {
      return {
        priority: 99, // it needs to run after the attributes are interpolated
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          var propName = attrName,
              name = attrName;

          if (attrName === 'href' &&
              toString.call(element.prop('href')) === '[object SVGAnimatedString]') {
            name = 'xlinkHref';
            attr.$attr[name] = 'xlink:href';
            propName = null;
          }

          attr.$observe(normalized, function(value) {
            if (!value)
               return;

            var attributes = {};
            $.each(element[0].attributes, function(){attributes[cloudinaryAttr(this.name)] = this.value});
            value = $.cloudinary.url(value, attributes);
            attr.$set(name, value);

            // on IE, if "ng:src" directive declaration is used and "src" attribute doesn't exist
            // then calling element.setAttribute('src', 'foo') doesn't do anything, so we need
            // to set the property as well to achieve the desired effect.
            // we use attr[attrName] value since $set can sanitize the url.
            if ($sniffer.msie && propName) element.prop(propName, attr[name]);
          });
        }
      };
    });
  });

  angularModule.directive('clTransformation', function() {
    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      transclude : false,
      require: '^clImage',
      link : function (scope, element, attrs, clImageCtrl) {
        var attributes = {};
        $.each(attrs, function(name,value){
          if (name[0] !== '$') {
            attributes[cloudinaryAttr(name)] = value;
          }
        });
        clImageCtrl.addTransformation(attributes);
      }
    }
  });

  angularModule.directive('clImage', function() {
    var Controller = function($scope) {
      this.addTransformation = function(ts) {
        $scope.transformations = $scope.transformations || [];
        $scope.transformations.push(ts);
      }
    };
    Controller.$inject = ['$scope'];
    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude : true,
      template: "<img ng-transclude/>",
      scope: {},
      priority: 99,
      controller: Controller,
      // The linking function will add behavior to the template
      link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var attributes = {};
        $.each(attrs, function(name, value){attributes[cloudinaryAttr(name)] = value});

        if (scope.transformations) {
          attributes.transformation = scope.transformations;
        }

        attrs.$observe('publicId', function(publicId){
          if (!publicId) return;
          var url = $.cloudinary.url(publicId, attributes);
          element.attr('src', url);
        });

        if (attrs.htmlWidth) {
          element.attr("width", attrs.htmlWidth);
        } else {
          element.removeAttr("width");
        }
        if (attrs.htmlHeight) {
          element.attr("height", attrs.htmlHeight);
        } else {
          element.removeAttr("height");
        }

      }
    };
  });
}));
```

**angular-file-upload.min.js**

```
/*! 1.6.6 */ !function() {
        "use strict";
        var a = angular.module('angularFileUpload', []);
        a.service("$upload", ["$http", "$q", "$timeout",
            function(a, b, c) {
                function d(d) {
                    d.method = d.method || "POST", d.headers = d.headers || {}, d.transformRequest = d.transformRequest || function(b, c) {
                        return window.ArrayBuffer && b instanceof window.ArrayBuffer ? b : a.defaults.transformRequest[0](b, c)
                    };
                    var e = b.defer();
                    window.XMLHttpRequest.__isShim && (d.headers.__setXHR_ = function() {
                        return function(a) {
                            a && (d.__XHR = a, d.xhrFn && d.xhrFn(a), a.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(a) {
                                e.notify(a)
                            }, !1), a.upload.addEventListener("load", function(a) {
                                a.lengthComputable && e.notify(a)
                            }, !1))
                        }
                    }), a(d).then(function(a) {
                        e.resolve(a)
                    }, function(a) {
                        e.reject(a)
                    }, function(a) {
                        e.notify(a)
                    });
                    var f = e.promise;
                    return f.success = function(a) {
                        return f.then(function(b) {
                            a(b.data, b.status, b.headers, d)
                        }), f
                    }, f.error = function(a) {
                        return f.then(null, function(b) {
                            a(b.data, b.status, b.headers, d)
                        }), f
                    }, f.progress = function(a) {
                        return f.then(null, null, function(b) {
                            a(b)
                        }), f
                    }, f.abort = function() {
                        return d.__XHR && c(function() {
                            d.__XHR.abort()
                        }), f
                    }, f.xhr = function(a) {
                        return d.xhrFn = function(b) {
                            return function() {
                                b && b.apply(f, arguments), a.apply(f, arguments)
                            }
                        }(d.xhrFn), f
                    }, f
                }
                this.upload = function(b) {
                    b.headers = b.headers || {}, b.headers["Content-Type"] = void 0, b.transformRequest = b.transformRequest || a.defaults.transformRequest;
                    var c = new FormData,
                        e = b.transformRequest,
                        f = b.data;
                    return b.transformRequest = function(a, c) {
                        if (f)
                            if (b.formDataAppender)
                                for (var d in f) {
                                    var g = f[d];
                                    b.formDataAppender(a, d, g)
                                } else
                                    for (var d in f) {
                                        var g = f[d];
                                        if ("function" == typeof e) g = e(g, c);
                                        else
                                            for (var h = 0; h < e.length; h++) {
                                                var i = e[h];
                                                "function" == typeof i && (g = i(g, c))
                                            }
                                        a.append(d, g)
                                    }
                            if (null != b.file) {
                                var j = b.fileFormDataName || "file";
                                if ("[object Array]" === Object.prototype.toString.call(b.file))
                                    for (var k = "[object String]" === Object.prototype.toString.call(j), h = 0; h < b.file.length; h++) a.append(k ? j : j[h], b.file[h], b.fileName && b.fileName[h] || b.file[h].name);
                                else a.append(j, b.file, b.fileName || b.file.name)
                            }
                        return a
                    }, b.data = c, d(b)
                }, this.http = function(a) {
                    return d(a)
                }
            }
        ]), a.directive("ngFileSelect", ["$parse", "$timeout",
            function(a, b) {
                return function(c, d, e) {
                    var f = a(e.ngFileSelect);
                    if ("input" !== d[0].tagName.toLowerCase() || "file" !== (d.attr("type") && d.attr("type").toLowerCase())) {
                        for (var g = angular.element('<input type="file">'), h = 0; h < d[0].attributes.length; h++) g.attr(d[0].attributes[h].name, d[0].attributes[h].value);
                        d.attr("data-multiple") && g.attr("multiple", "true"), g.css("top", 0).css("bottom", 0).css("left", 0).css("right", 0).css("width", "100%").css("opacity", 0).css("position", "absolute").css("filter", "alpha(opacity=0)"), d.append(g), g.parent()[0] != d[0] && (d.wrap("<span>"), d.css("z-index", "-1000"), d.parent().append(g), d = d.parent()), ("" === d.css("position") || "static" === d.css("position")) && d.css("position", "relative"), d = g
                    }
                    d.bind("change", function(a) {
                        var d, e, g = [];
                        if (d = a.__files_ || a.target.files, null != d)
                            for (e = 0; e < d.length; e++) g.push(d.item(e));
                        b(function() {
                            f(c, {
                                $files: g,
                                $event: a
                            })
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
        ]), a.directive("ngFileDropAvailable", ["$parse", "$timeout",
            function(a, b) {
                return function(c, d, e) {
                    if ("draggable" in document.createElement("span")) {
                        var f = a(e.ngFileDropAvailable);
                        b(function() {
                            f(c)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        ]), a.directive("ngFileDrop", ["$parse", "$timeout", "$location",
            function(a, b, c) {
                return function(d, e, f) {
                    function g(a) {
                        return /^[\000-\177]*$/.test(a)
                    }

                    function h(a, d) {
                        var e = [],
                            f = a.dataTransfer.items;
                        if (f && f.length > 0 && f[0].webkitGetAsEntry && "file" != c.protocol() && f[0].webkitGetAsEntry().isDirectory)
                            for (var h = 0; h < f.length; h++) {
                                var j = f[h].webkitGetAsEntry();
                                null != j && (g(j.name) ? i(e, j) : f[h].webkitGetAsEntry().isDirectory || e.push(f[h].getAsFile()))
                            } else {
                                var k = a.dataTransfer.files;
                                if (null != k)
                                    for (var h = 0; h < k.length; h++) e.push(k.item(h))
                            }! function m(a) {
                                b(function() {
                                    l ? m(10) : d(e)
                                }, a || 0)
                            }()
                    }

                    function i(a, b, c) {
                        if (null != b)
                            if (b.isDirectory) {
                                var d = b.createReader();
                                l++, d.readEntries(function(d) {
                                    for (var e = 0; e < d.length; e++) i(a, d[e], (c ? c : "") + b.name + "/");
                                    l--
                                })
                            } else l++, b.file(function(b) {
                                l--, b._relativePath = (c ? c : "") + b.name, a.push(b)
                            })
                    }
                    if ("draggable" in document.createElement("span")) {
                        var j = null;
                        e[0].addEventListener("dragover", function(c) {
                            if (c.preventDefault(), b.cancel(j), !e[0].__drag_over_class_)
                                if (f.ngFileDragOverClass && f.ngFileDragOverClass.search(/\) *$/) > -1) {
                                    dragOverClassFn = a(f.ngFileDragOverClass);
                                    var g = dragOverClassFn(d, {
                                        $event: c
                                    });
                                    e[0].__drag_over_class_ = g
                                } else e[0].__drag_over_class_ = f.ngFileDragOverClass || "dragover";
                            e.addClass(e[0].__drag_over_class_)
                        }, !1), e[0].addEventListener("dragenter", function(a) {
                            a.preventDefault()
                        }, !1), e[0].addEventListener("dragleave", function() {
                            j = b(function() {
                                e.removeClass(e[0].__drag_over_class_), e[0].__drag_over_class_ = null
                            }, f.ngFileDragOverDelay || 1)
                        }, !1);
                        var k = a(f.ngFileDrop);
                        e[0].addEventListener("drop", function(a) {
                            a.preventDefault(), e.removeClass(e[0].__drag_over_class_), e[0].__drag_over_class_ = null, h(a, function(b) {
                                k(d, {
                                    $files: b,
                                    $event: a
                                })
                            })
                        }, !1);
                        var l = 0
                    }
                }
            }
        ])
    };
```

Should I include '$http' '$q' before loading angular-file-upload.js ? My error now is 
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularFileUpload due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularFileUpload' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Apparently angular is not loaded yet when this bit of cade call for it, check in your dev tools if angular js file is loaded at all

Comment: Hi please find my updated code in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what 'Itay Taragano' told, I just installed "$http", "$q", "$timeout" these modules also. that worked!

Answer (score 3):

You should verify the correct ordering of the JS files, as shown here:
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/blob/master/samples/photo_album/app/index.html#L21
Note that the `angular-file-upload-shim.min.js` is before `angular.js` before `angular.cloudinary.js` before `angular-file-upload.min.js`